# If the character 'p' is in a word, add the word to a list variable

Tags: python

So my assignment is this: Using the file school_prompt.txt, if the character ‘p’ is in a word, then add the word to a list called p_words.

I'm not sure what progress I've made but I've gotten stuck.

```
wordsFile = open("school_prompt.txt", 'r')
words = wordsFile.read()
wordsFile.close()
wordList = words.split()
p_words = 0

for words in wordList:
    if words[0] == 'p':
        p_words += 1
```

Comment: A string is an iterable, i.e. you can loop over it, so you can do `if 'p' in words:`.

Answer (score 5):

What you want is pretty straightforward; I'm not sure why you are making `p_words` a count of words instead of a list of words.

```
p_words = [word for word in wordList if 'p' in word]
```

Answer (score 1):

As answered by Henrik, this could be done by using the if statement. Also the p_words should be a list not a variable.

```
file=open("school_prompt.txt","r")
p_words=[]
file=file.read()
wordlist=file.split()
for i in wordlist:
    if 'p' in i:
        p_words.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works and I tried to do one line of code using list comprehension but couldnt get it to work.

```
fileref = open('school_prompt.txt', 'r')
words = fileref.read().split()
p_words = [word for word in words if 'p' in word]
```

Answer (score 0):

we need to do for loop inside for loop to check for the words contain letter "p".
Here's the code.

```
file = open("school_prompt.txt", "r")
content = file.readlines()
p_words = []
for lines in content:
    lines = lines.split()
    for words in lines:
        if "p" in words:
            p_words.append(words)
print(p_words)
```